# Blender crashes when enabling "true" displacement

Tags: materials, displacement, memory-management, osl

I created an OSL shader (a 4D noise texture) and connected it to the "Displacement" output of my shader. I wanted this to be a animated micropolygon / adaptive subdivision displacement, so I enabled "Experimental" of course.

When I go to make the Displacement type "true" though, Blender consistently crashes, probably due to memory overload. I don't have an especially high vertex count, though.

How can I work around / fix this?

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZfHEgYwf_iuuY3aWEoH0n-sXVHCibXNO/view?usp=sharing) video shows the problem, it's through Google Drive.

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8138/how-to-animate-noise-texture-seed) is the Stackexchange question that help peed me create the OSL shader

And, finally, [here](https://youtu.be/_cbcV1_rgZg) is the video that was guiding me through the Micropolygon Displacement process.

EDIT: Here is my OSL code.

```c
#include "stdosl.h"

shader simple_noise_texture4d(
float Scale = 1.0,
float Time = 0.0,
output color Color = 0.0
)
{
    Color = noise( "uperlin", P * Scale, Time );
}
```

Comment: Potentially related? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69023/render-fails-at-tesselation-with-out-of-memory-error/69024#69024

Comment: Can you post your OSL code?

Comment: Done. Anything else that would help?

Comment: Does it display an error message when you run "blender.exe --debug-memory" in the command prompt?

Comment: Just tried that, and no, no error message is displayed. I can open blender fine in memory debug mode. Then, when I try to switch it to 'True' it still crashes. So, probably not a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't explain the crash but does offer a way to work around the issue.

I noticed that your OSL script is generating a *Color* to pass into the Displacement. The Displacement is a Scalar value (at the moment - I believe the future incarnation of True Displacement will offer a Vector - much more versatile) and so there is no benefit in generating your displacement as a Color - it will be converted to and interpreted as a scalar value anyway.

By amending the OSL code to generate a *float* rather than *Color*, Blender no longer seems to crash :

[image]

---

Further to this, it appears to be specific to the *type* of noise used. For example, changing using 'usimplex' instead of 'uperlin' does not trigger the issue - also fine for 'cell', 'simplex', 'perlin' (without the 'u'), 'gabor', etc. all seem to work fine but for some reason 'uperlin' causes the crash - but only if you actually try to 'use' one of the elements of the color (eg, `color c = noise('uperlin’, P*Scale, Time); Displacement = c[0];` causes it to crash).