# Adaptive Subsurface does not render. Error: std::length_error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, subdivision-surface

I'm trying to render something with with an Adaptive Subsurface modifier.

In my scene I'm not that close up so I was wondering why it took so long to start rendering on my own machine. So I put it on my rendering server and it gave the following error message.

I tried in on 2 servers and have no clue why it does not work.

Other angles of the render do work ( side view for example ).

Error message:
[image]

Scene ( 2 objects with array and mirror modifiers )
[image]

Modifiers:

[image]

Comment: The renderer  is trying to reserve memory for a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) bigger than your system can handle. > 4Gb by the looks.

Comment: System has 32GB though..

Comment: Found this as my solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69023/render-fails-at-tesselation-with-out-of-memory-error